# List of target architectures supported by GNAT?

Tags: compiler-construction, embedded, ada, gnat, target-platform

I'd like to know which CPU architectures, espescially in the embedded sector, are supported by GNAT. Is every target supported by the gnu C compiler automatically also supported for Ada?

Comment: -pedant here - by gnu C compiler do you mean gcc ? if so its now officially Gnu Compiler Collection.

Comment: No, I mean the C compiler that is part of the gcc (gnu compiler collection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AdaCore's [Embedded Development Page](http://www.adacore.com/gnatpro/embedded/) has the list.

Comment: Sadly, this link is now dead.

Answer (score 3):

More seriously, a quick reading of `man gcc` shows me no restriction between language & architecture. Not that one may not exist.

Promisingly though, the statement :

> If the description for a particular option does not mention a source
>   language, you can use that option with all supported languages.

from `man gcc` seems to imply a Yes to your question.

Comment: The quote just means that all the options listed apply to all source languages. Unfortunately, man gcc has nothing to say about the `-b` option.

Comment: well, you still need a runtime library, which is dependant on the target architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the factoid I wrote for the #Ada IRC channel on Freenode, it answers your question:

target x:  In theory any platform can be targetted by an Ada compiler, in practice it depends on the target's hardware, i.e. if the target is embedded and very limited, there may only be a subset of Ada you can implement on said target.
 or: A good way to see if a particular target you are interested in can be targetted by Ada is to check to see if the target CPU is supported by a GCC backend, if it is, then you look to see if GNAT has a front end for it, it may only support a subset, it may not support it at all, in this case you have to do some work on the GNAT front end of the compiler to support this target.
 or: The list of GCC backends can be found at http://gcc.gnu.org/backends.html
 or: You can find out if GNAT supports a particular CPU/OS combination by looking in /gcc/ada/gcc-interface/Makefile.in by looking at the pattern matching lines that look like "ifeq ($(strip $(filter-out mips% wrs vx%,$(targ))),)" this pattern matches the MIPS CPU with the Wind River Systems vxWorks operating system.
 or: See Secton 3.17 of the GCC Manual for hardware specific options, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs

I shall add the above link to AdaCore.